# Is Recent Activity Stream separated from Profile Feed stream?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-profile

We need to access facebook user's public status updates and comments in our application. And we are using [this](https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=%3Caccess_token%3E) for fetching this information. Until last week we were successfully getting likes, comments and now friends updates via this API. However, now suddenly this week they are gone and we are not receiving any of such things (e.g. xxx likes xxx or xxx commented on xxx's status or xxx,xxx and xxxx are now friends) via Profile Feed API. We have noticed that this thing has some relationship on Timeline feature of Facebook because in Timeline view of a user's profile we get the concerned updates in Activity Log tab of Profile page. So, here are my two questions regarding this:

1. Is likes, comments and friends updates are removed from Profile Feed Stream?
2. If answer to #1 is yes, then is there any stream available via Graph API to get these updates?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, any time I query /userid/feed for a bunch of different users I see some of the stories you describe. So, I think the answer is that, no, they haven't been removed.

Comment: @MatthewJohnston Actually, we were getting a update stating "xxx commented on xxx's photo" last week for a user, but now we are not getting this feed while we are getting feeds which were updated before and after this particular feed.

Comment: If that's true and you can reproduce it (find a user that is still not on Timeline and request their feed for example) then you should file a bug about this in the [Bug Tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)

Comment: @MatthewJohnston it seems it is fine again. We haven't change a single bit of code for this, but it is now fetching the records as usual. However, I have one more question, Can we fetch user's recent activity from facebook. I am particularly interested in likes of feeds,shares, statuses etc. I know there is an api for fetching user likes but that return user's activities,movies,music and interests etc not the status, comment or share like.